# How to order ggplot legend of plot with numeric data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to make a plot with `ggplot2` I have difficulties to order the legend as I want. For debugging I made some example data and the issue doesn't occur though data and code are similar! I am confused of in which way `ggplot` sorts its data.

The legend should be sorted by its values since it's numeric, as it actually is in the example data, but not in my working data.

**Here's my data...**

```
structure(list(n = c(150000, 15000, 3000, 1500, 750), estimate = c(0.0485706666666667, 
0.0454933333333333, 0.0604, 0.0413333333333334, 0.0402666666666666
), se = c(0.00230392190029327, 0.00727258789388646, 0.0163963824219692, 
0.0229426160506936, 0.0324210840623078), t.value = c(21.0811338041398, 
6.25147550973637, 3.67790396107066, 1.80003749831851, 1.23787262678884
)), .Names = c("n", "estimate", "se", "t.value"), row.names = c("150000", 
"15000", "3000", "1500", "750"), class = "data.frame")
```

**...and code I used to make the df**

```
# allEst <- data.frame(rbind(est1, est2, est3, est4, est5))  
# names(allEst) <- names(est1.tmp)
# rownames(allEst) <- c(150000, 15000, 3000, 1500, 750)
```

**Code for the plot**

```
# confidence intervals
interval1 <- - qnorm((1 - .95) / 2)  # 5% 
interval2 <- - qnorm((1 - .99) / 2)  # 1% 

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ep <- ggplot(allEst, aes(colour=rownames(allEst)))
ep <- ep + geom_hline(yintercept=0.05, colour=gray(1/2), lty=2)
ep <- ep + geom_linerange(aes(x=n,
                                ymin=estimate - se*interval1, 
                                ymax=estimate + se*interval1),
                            lwd=2)
ep <- ep + geom_pointrange(aes(x=n, y=estimate, 
                                 ymin=estimate - se*interval2, 
                                 ymax=estimate + se*interval2),
                             lwd=1, shape=21, fill="WHITE")
ep <- ep + scale_x_log10()
ep <- ep + coord_flip() 

print(ep)
```

**Which gives me:**

[image]

**And here the toy example I created:**

```
est1 <- c(1e5, 0.0485, 0.0023, 21.08)
est2 <- c(1e4, 0.0454, 0.0072, 6.25)
est3 <- c(1e3, 0.0604, 0.0163, 3.67)
est4 <- c(1e2, 0.0402, 0.0324, 1.23)

df <- data.frame(rbind(est1, est2, est3, est4))
rownames(df) <- c(100000, 10000, 1000, 100)
df

interval1 <- - qnorm(0.025); interval2 <- - qnorm(0.005)

library(ggplot2)
ep1 <- ggplot(df, aes(colour=rownames(df)))
ep1 <- ep1 + geom_hline(yintercept=0.05, colour=gray(1/2), lty=2)
ep1 <- ep1 + geom_linerange(aes(x=X1, ymin= X2 -  X3*interval1,
                                ymax= X2 +  X3*interval1),
                            lwd=2, position=position_dodge(width=1/2))
ep1 <- ep1 + geom_pointrange(aes(x=X1, y= X2, ymin= X2 - 
                                    X3*interval2, ymax= X2 + 
                                    X3*interval2),
                             lwd=1, position=position_dodge(width=1/2),
                             shape=21, fill="WHITE")
ep1 <- ep1 + scale_x_log10()
ep1 <- ep1 + coord_flip() 

print(ep1)
```

**...and the plot w/ perfectly ordered (!) legend:**

[image]

So, what's going on? Where am I blind?

Comment: It has to do with lexicographic sorting vs numeric sorting. In your simple example, try 100, 50, 2, 3000. If you are using discrete values for coloring, then they are sorted "alphabetically." You can override that manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reorder color legend with `breaks` from `scale_color_discrete`:

```
# Adding sorted rownames to breaks
ep + scale_color_discrete(breaks = sort(as.numeric(rownames(allEst))))
```

Result plot:

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! Just why the difference between my two versions?

Answer (score 3):

You pass a character vector from `rownames(allEst)` to the aesthetics, which are sorted as a character:

```
sort(rownames(allEst))
[1] "1500"   "15000"  "150000" "3000"   "750"
```

If `sort` is used on characters, it uses alphabetic sorting, where `'1'` and `'12'` are before `'2'` just like `'a'` and `'ab'` are before `'ba'`. If you look at the difference between

```
sort(c(1:3, 10, 20, 30))
```

which returns

```
[1] 1 2 3 10 20 30
```

and

```
sort(as.character(c(1:3, 10, 20, 30)))
```

which returns

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YMud.png) "1" "10" "2" "20" "3" "30"

it might be clearer.

One way of changing that would be using `factor(sort(as.numeric(rownames(allEst))))`. Integrated in your code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ep <- ggplot(allEst, aes(colour=factor(sort(as.numeric(rownames(allEst))))))
ep <- ep + geom_hline(yintercept=0.05, colour=gray(1/2), lty=2)
ep <- ep + geom_linerange(aes(x=n,
                              ymin=estimate - se*interval1, 
                              ymax=estimate + se*interval1),
                          lwd=2)
ep <- ep + geom_pointrange(aes(x=n, y=estimate, 
                               ymin=estimate - se*interval2, 
                               ymax=estimate + se*interval2),
                           lwd=1, shape=21, fill="WHITE")
ep <- ep + scale_x_log10()
ep <- ep + coord_flip() 

print(ep)
```

Returns:
[image: output_ggplot]

Comment: That's exactly what I find hard to understand, why the difference between `sort(rownames(allEst))`: [1] "1500"   "15000"  "150000" "3000"   "750"  and  `sort(rownames(df))`: [1] "100"   "1000"  "10000" "1e+05"

Comment: This is the way `sort` is defined. If it is used on characters, it uses alphabetic sorting, where `'1'` and `'12'` are before `'2'` just like `'a'` and '`ab'` are before '`ba'`. If you look at the difference between `sort(c(1:3, 10, 20, 30))` which returns `[1]  1  2  3 10 20 30` and `sort(as.character(c(1:3, 10, 20, 30)))` which returns `[1] "1"  "10" "2"  "20" "3"  "30"` it might be clearer.